# MYSQL update or insert rows if id doesnt exist

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a datatable with many, many rows. I use the table to store information about materials that combine to form a quote. The rows are identified by a specific ID, but also by the quote ID. As I add or remove materials, I want to update the rows applicable, add rows if new materials are added, or remove rows if materials are removed on save. The issue is each time a row is added, the table primary key increases (unique row ID). Is it best practise to remove all rows where Quote ID matches, then insert all the rows again? If this happens each time I save, will this potentially make the primary key too large? I have many users who interract with this datatable.

Does the datatable need to have a primary key?

Comment: Will a `BIGINT` ever get "too large"? My guess: No. Even if you're doing a billion inserts per second for a hundred years, you're good.

Comment: No, the table does not _need_ a primary key, in that the server will let you create the table without it... but you absolutely should use one. Additionally, incrementing IDs are not the only possible primary key. You could use a natural key instead, if you wanted. However, incrementing IDs are a common choice for good reason: they are efficient to do lookups for specific records, you can guarantee they'll be immutable and non-colliding, and they make for efficient inserts (always add to the end of the last page, and never need to split pages as the result of an insert).

Comment: Thanks. Will sql query performance slow if the table becomes massive, or bigint primary key is large?

Comment: @MatSparrow That depends on the application and how the server is provisioned, but generally the answer is that BIGINT will not cause a meaningful performance issue for a reasonably designed application or server. It's just an extra 4 bytes per record, and the database has highly-optimized code to keep the comparisons and lookups as efficient as possible.

Comment: You’re a legend. Thankyou

Comment: you can use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update or insert depending on whether it already exists. But there's no way to combine `DELETE` with that. You should use a transaction around all of them to ensure other processes see a consistent state.